# Swift Bar button item set to system item "save" ignores app language

Tags: ios, swift, locale

In my app I have a bar button item in my top navigation bar. I have set the button system item to "Save" which will display the button as **Save**

But even if my phone has a different language set the button still shows up with the text "Save"- english when I start the app

Comment: What localizations does your app currently support?

Comment: I think @rmaddy has put his finger on it. It isn't about the phone, it's about your app. (By the way, you can test without changing phone settings; there are scheme settings for switching languages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language that various UI components appear in your app is based on two things:

1. The device's list of languages under the "Preferred Language Order" section of the "Language & Region" page of the Settings app.
2. The languages supported by your app as defined by the localization bundles your app provides.

An app only supports a single language by default. To support additional languages you must add an additional bundle for each language and then provide appropriate localization resources such as strings files and localized storyboards, etc.

Based on your app's supported languages and the devices settings, UI components will appear in a single, chosen language.

Lets say your app supports English, Spanish, and Chinese.

Now lets say a user's device has the languages German and English, in that order, listed on the Language & Region screen.

Your app will appear in English to this user. Based on your question, you seem to expect the Save button to appear in German. But if your app doesn't support German, why have the Save button appear in German and the rest of the app appear in English? That would be confusing.

So now go back to the simple case. You have a basic app and you haven't done any localization yet. Your app only has the one bundle - the default language for your app. Lets say that is English. Since your app only supports English, it would be really confusing for the Save button to be in any other language while the rest of the app is in English. So no matter what language the user has set for their device, the Save button will be in the app's only language, English in this example.